# how to start time in minutes from specific time such as from 9 AM to PM

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, data-structures

I want to start my time in minutes from 9 AM to 9 PM

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in your title:

You can create a `Date` and use `setHours`, `setMinutes`, etc. to set its time to 9.00 in the morning.

You can then use `-` to find the difference in milliseconds between two dates. By dividing by `1000 * 60`, you can calculate the difference in minutes.

```js
const minutesSinceNineInTheMorning = (dateTime) => {
  const nineInTheMorning = new Date(dateTime);
  nineInTheMorning.setHours(9);
  nineInTheMorning.setMinutes(0);
  nineInTheMorning.setSeconds(0);
  nineInTheMorning.setMilliseconds(0);
  
  const msInAMinute = 1000 * 60;
  
  return (dateTime - nineInTheMorning) / msInAMinute;
};

console.log(minutesSinceNineInTheMorning(new Date()));
```

The remaining questions are a matter of finding overlap between blocks, which should be doable now that you have regular numbers to work with.

If you still need help with the last problems, it's probably best to ask a new question or show some tries specific to the required logic.

P.S. Here's a quick example I wrote during my lunch break that might help you get started:

```js
const requestByJohn = { start: 220, end: 280, name: "John" };
const options = [
 {start: 225, end: 285, name: "Jane" },
 {start: 210, end: 270, name: "Aisha"},
 {start: 180, end: 240, name: "Brad" },
 {start: 180, end: 330, name: "Alice"},
 {start: 300, end: 360, name: "Yusef"},
 {start: 270, end: 330, name: "Rob"  }
];

const match = req => opt => ({
  // Calculate the overlap between two blocks
  overlap: opt.end <= req.start || opt.start > req.end
    ? 0
    : Math.min(req.end, opt.end) - Math.max(req.start, opt.start),
  // The earliest start time of this meeting
  start: Math.max(req.start, opt.start),
  label: `${req.name} - ${opt.name}`
});

const overlapRule = ({ overlap }) => overlap >= 30;
const sortLogic = (m1, m2) => 
  // Sort by overlap first
  m2.overlap > m1.overlap ?  1 : 
  m2.overlap < m1.overlap ? -1 :
  // Sort by start second
  m2.start > m1.start     ? -1 :
  m2.start < m1.start     ?  1 :
                             0 ;

// Chain match, filter, sort:
const bestMatches = options
  .map(match(requestByJohn))
  .filter(overlapRule)
  .sort(sortLogic);
  
console.log(
  "Best match:",
  bestMatches[0],
  "\nAll possibilities:",
  bestMatches
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Comment: is this solution related to any specific data structure?

Comment: I'm sorry if the lunch break comment sounded condescending, I didn't mean it that way. I just wanted to emphasize I hadn't had time to completely explain the logic behind the code. If you want to exclude the lunchbreak, add a `lunchOverlap` property to the match. In your filter, force it to be `0`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have time to dig in to how to build a UI. It's probably best if you remove the snippet you've posted as an answer and ask a new question with a specific problem statement. E.g.: How to add a block to a jquery-ui timepicker?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> index.html
> ```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Brilliant Lunch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="time">
        <span class="span-large">09:00 AM</span>
        <span class="span-small">9:30 AM</span>
        <span class="span-large">10:00 AM</span>
        <span class="span-small">10:30 AM</span>
        <span class="span-large">11:00 AM</span>
        <span class="span-small">11:30 AM</span>
        <span class="span-large">12:00 AM</span>
        <span class="span-small">12:30 AM</span>
        <span class="span-large">01:00 AM</span>
        <span class="span-small">01:30 AM</span>
        <span class="span-large">02:00 AM</span>
        <span class="span-small">02:30 AM</span>
        <span class="span-large">03:00 AM</span>
        <span class="span-small">03:30 AM</span>
        <span class="span-large">04:00 AM</span>
        <span class="span-small">04:30 AM</span>
        <span class="span-large">05:00 AM</span>
        <span class="span-small">05:30 AM</span>
        <span class="span-large">06:00 AM</span>
        <span class="span-small">06:30 AM</span>
        <span class="span-large">07:00 AM</span>
        <span class="span-small">07:30 AM</span>
        <span class="span-large">08:00 AM</span>
        <span class="span-small">08:30 AM</span>
        <span class="span-large">09:00 AM</span>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="main_Content">
      <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

> style

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 610px;
  height: 720px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background: #ECECEC;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.time {
  height: 720px;
  width: 100px;
}
.span-large {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 38%;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #666;

}
.span-small {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-left: 50.1%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  color: #666;
}
```

> main.js

```
"use strict"

const requestByJohn = { start: 220, end: 280, name: "John" };
const options = [
 {start: 225, end: 285, name: "Jane" },
 {start: 210, end: 270, name: "Aisha"},
 {start: 180, end: 240, name: "Brad" },
 {start: 180, end: 330, name: "Alice"},
 {start: 300, end: 360, name: "Yusef"},
 {start: 270, end: 330, name: "Rob"  }
];

const match = req => opt => ({
  // Calculate the overlap between two blocks
  overlap: opt.end <= req.start || opt.start > req.end
    ? 0
    : Math.min(req.end, opt.end) - Math.max(req.start, opt.start),
  // The earliest start time of this meeting
  start: Math.max(req.start, opt.start),
  label: `${req.name} - ${opt.name}`
});

const overlapRule = ({ overlap }) => overlap >= 30;
const sortLogic = (m1, m2) => 
  // Sort by overlap first
  m2.overlap > m1.overlap ?  1 : 
  m2.overlap < m1.overlap ? -1 :
  // Sort by start second
  m2.start > m1.start     ? -1 :
  m2.start < m1.start     ?  1 :
                             0 ;

// Chain match, filter, sort:
const matchLunchEvent = options
  .map(match(requestByJohn))
  .filter(overlapRule)
  .sort(sortLogic);

console.log(
  "Brilliant Lunch:",
  matchLunchEvent[0],
  "\nAll possibilities:",
  matchLunchEvent
)
```